# Realm format date JSON swift

Tags: json, swift2, realm

I had JSON with a date "date_use" :

```
 {"expense":
    {"id":1,
    "amount":123.3,
    "date_use":"2015-07-04T00:00:00Z"}
 }
```

I had an error on date format when I execute this code :

```
self.realm!.create(Expense.self, value:json["expense"].object, update: true)
```

Error :

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason:
>   'Invalid value '2015-07-04T00:00:00Z' for property 'date_use'

My question is : What is the good date format for Realm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is not the particular date format, but that JSON doesn't support a native date type at all. So you have to serialize dates to a string format. Using [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339), like you have to deal with, is generally a good choice because it avoids ambiguities, so you can stick with that.

Realm's [`create`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Realm.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift5Realm6createFS0_U__FTMQ_5valuePSs9AnyObject_6updateSb_Q_) method doesn't expect deserialized JSON, but a dictionary representation of your object. This expects that you have done already the preprocessing step of transforming date string representations back to Cocoa's native type `NSDate`. This isn't done automatically because there are date formats, which are ambiguous (unlike yours), which e.g do not provide information about the timezone.

Good news is there are excellent third-party libraries e.g. [Realm-JSON](https://github.com/matthewcheok/Realm-JSON), which make it a whole lot easier to deal with that. It brings built-in support for that.
This would also allow to map the property naming scheme returned by your API, e.g. `date_use` to names which conforms to the more broadly used camel-case `dateUse`.

If you don't want to introduce another dependency just for that use case, you can use and [configure NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW7) to parse dates conforming to your particular subset of the RFC 3339 standard, assuming they always use UTC as timezone, marked through the `Z` suffix.

```
// Setup the RFC 3339 date formatter
let rfc3339DateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
let enUSPOSIXLocale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
rfc3339DateFormatter.locale = enUSPOSIXLocale
rfc3339DateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"
rfc3339DateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)

// Convert the RFC 3339 date time string to an NSDate
var json: AnyObject! = nil
var value = json["expense"] as! [String : AnyObject]
let date: NSDate?
if let dateString = value["date_use"] as? String {
    date = rfc3339DateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
} else {
    date = nil
}
value["date_use"] = date

// Create your object
self.realm!.create(Expense.self, value: value, update: true)
```

Comment: For reference: support for that directly in the binding is tracked by [realm-cocoa#1013](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1013).